# Unity - Using components as interface

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inheritance, interface

**The need :**

To have the possibility to interact with `Component` instances of different type attached on `GameObject` instances through an `interface`.

For exemple, if I have a game with soldiers, and assuming that medics and snipers both are soldiers, I want to be able to get the `Soldier` component attached to a soldier `GameObject`, regardless of whether that soldier is actually a `Sniper` or a `Medic`. Then, I could do something as follows : `soldier.GetComponent<Soldier>().Respawn();` which would end up calling either `Medic.Respawn()` or `Sniper.Respawn()`, depending on the actual type of the soldier.

**Possible but dirty solution 1 :**

A first naive approach would be to have the `Sniper` and `Medic` components implement a `Soldier` `interface`. However, this causes several problems.

For example, if you want to check whether a `GameObject` has a component implementing `Soldier`, you can't, because `Soldier` is only an interface, not an actual Unity `Component`. Thus, calling `GetComponent<Soldier>()` on a `GameObject` having, for exemple, a `Medic` component would not return that `Medic` component, even if `Medic` does implement `Soldier`.

(Actually you could check this by iterating over all the components and using the `is` operator, but that would be dirty and slow).

**Possible but dirty solution 2 :**

A second approach is to create a base `Component` class `Soldier` from which the `Medic` and `Sniper` classes would inherit.

But this also poses several problems.

First, the Unity events (`Awake()`, `Start()`, etc) are only going to be called on the leaf classes of the hierachy, forcing you to manually call the same functions on the parent class. Anyone who has tried that knows that it's easy to forget calling something, which results in improperly initialized objects, for example.

And second, the usual problems of inheritance are here too. For exemple, if I want my `Medic` and `Sniper` componenents to not only be `Soldier`, but also be `Explodable` or `VehicleDriver` or whatever, I can't, because C# does not support multiple inheritance.

**The approach I'm thinking about :**

I've thought about a way to design my code so that the issues listed above are solved.

The idea is to have a `Component` class that acts as the interface and have that interface component coexist with the acutal component on the same `GameObject`. In other words, let two game objects. One of them would have both a `Soldier` and a `Medic` component and the other one would have both a `Soldier` and a `Sniper` component. All three component classes, i.e `Soldier`, `Medic` and `Sniper` would be completely separate and all inherit from `MonoBehaviour`.

The other parts of the code would only interact with the `Soldier` component.  In this case you would be able to do : `soldier.GetComponent<Soldier>().Respawn();`.

Then, it would be the resposibility of the "interface" component (i.e `Soldier`) to use the actual component (i.e `Medic` or `Sniper`) in order to perform the specific action.

However, since `Soldier` does not known anything about `Medic`, `Sniper` or whatever implementation might be added in the future, the `Soldier` component exposes an actual `interface` that the `Medic` and `Soldier` have to implement.

Since it is possible to implement multiple interfaces, using this solution, it would be possible to use more than one "interface" component. For exemple, a soldier game object could have the following "interface" components : `Soldier` and `Explodable`, and the following "actual" componenent : `Medic` which would implement both interfaces `Soldier.ISolder` and `Explodable.IExplodable`.

**What do you think about this solution ?** Thx !

### **EDIT :**

I coded what I had in mind and it seems to work nicely. I've also created an editor script allowing to have the "interface" component reference the "actual" component without having public fields, but properties instead. I'll post the code, just in case someone wants it :

`WaterComponent.cs` - The "interface" component for water objects :

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class WaterComponent : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region Interface

    public interface IWater
    {
        bool IsPointSubmerged(Vector3 worldPoint);

        Vector3 GetNormalAtPoint(Vector3 worldPoint);
    }

    #endregion Interface

    #region Properties

    public IWater Water
    {
        get
        {
            return waterImplementation;
        }
        set
        {
            Component asComponent = value as Component;

            if (null != value && null == waterComponent)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"The given {typeof(IWater).Name} is not a {typeof(Component).Name}.");
            }

            waterComponent = asComponent;
            waterImplementation = value;
        }
    }

    #endregion Properties

    #region Fields

    [SerializeField]
    private Component waterComponent;

    private IWater waterImplementation;

    #endregion Fields

    #region Public methods

    public bool IsPointSubmerged(Vector3 worldPoint)
    {
        return waterImplementation.IsPointSubmerged(worldPoint);
    }

    public Vector3 GetNormalAtPoint(Vector3 worldPoint)
    {
        return waterImplementation.GetNormalAtPoint(worldPoint);
    }

    #endregion Public methods

    #region Unity events

    private void Awake()
    {
        waterImplementation = waterComponent as IWater;
    }

    #endregion Unity events
}
```

RealWater.cs - The "actual" component implementing the "interface" component :

```
using UnityEngine;

public class RealWater : MonoBehaviour, WaterComponent.IWater
{
    #region WaterComponent.IWater implementation

    public bool IsPointSubmerged(Vector3 worldPoint)
    {
        return SpecificIsPointSubmerged(worldPoint);
    }

    public Vector3 GetNormalAtPoint(Vector3 worldPoint)
    {
        return SpecificGetWaterAtPoint(worldPoint);
    }

    #endregion WaterComponent.IWater implementation

    #region Non-public methods

    private bool SpecificIsPointSubmerged(Vector3 worldPoint)
    {
        return true;
    }

    private Vector3 SpecificGetWaterAtPoint(Vector3 worldPoint)
    {
        return transform.up;
    }

    #endregion Non-public methods
}
```

WaterComponentEditor.cs - The custom editor allowing not to have naked fields exposed :

using UnityEditor;

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(WaterComponent))]
[CanEditMultipleObjects]
public class WaterComponentEditor : Editor
{
    #region Serialized properties

    private SerializedProperty waterProperty;

    #endregion Serialized properties

    #region Overridden methods

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        serializedObject.Update();

        EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();

        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(waterProperty);

        if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
        {
            ((WaterComponent) target).Water = waterProperty.exposedReferenceValue as WaterComponent.IWater;
        }

        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }

    #endregion Overridden methods

    #region Unity events

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        waterProperty = serializedObject.FindProperty("waterComponent");
    }

    #endregion Unity events
}
```

Feel free to reuse, unless you see a flaw with this, in which case I'd would really like to know about it !!

EDIT : Well the problem with that custom editor is that you can have the "interface" component reference any `Component` even if the latter does not implement the real interface exposed by the "interface" component. It is still possible to do some run time checks in the custom editor script, but that's not so clean. However I think the advantages remain good enough in comparison to that issue.

Answer (score 1):

Well...

> GetComponent family of functions now supports interfaces as generic argument.

Unity 5.0 release notes : https://unity3d.com/fr/unity/whats-new/unity-5.0

Whatever...